# SSH cannot connect to server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, openssh, azure

I've got problem with connecting to my VM running on Linux. Recently I was playing with SSH server configuration and I set listening on port 2222. But now I can't connect to this server. How can I reset this settings ?

I've tried following, but it's not working:

```
ssh user@my.ip.address
ssh user@my.ip.address -p 2222
```

The question is **how can I connect to my machine?**

**EDIT:** I've already solved it - in Azure VM settings I reset SSH configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change ssh port to other port, you need open port on [Azure NSG](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg). By default, for a Linux VM, only port 22 is open. So, when you change the port to other, you could not ssh to the VM.

[image]

When you rest ssh configuration on Azure Portal, it will change port to 22. So, you could ssh to your VM again.

Comment: Ooh yes, of course. Thanks for explanation, I forgot to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by reseting SSH configuration in VM setting on Azure portal.[image]

Comment: You could change ssh port to 2222, the root reason that you could not ssh to your VM is you not open port 2222 on Azure NSG. If possible, I suggest you could test again.